# Why we need Apache Camel in our application?

Tags: apache-camel, microservices, camel-ftp

I am beginner to apache camel, and i need some clarity in it.
Apache camel is an alternative for microservices? Or what is the advantage of this routing integration.

It has separate HTTP component but its configuration method looks like

```
from("route1").to("route2")
```

so how it works when one request arrives in camel application.

Kindly guide me to know the basics of it.

Answer (score 1):

apache camel is an integration framework which helps you to connect many endpoints with different protocols together.There are lots of integrations for apache camel ready to use and no it is not an alternative to microservices but you can use it in microservice architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One request come to our application, whether it is redirected to same request or it will go to some other request using to() method. how it is useful in large applications

Comment: let me break it down like this suppose you have banking solution backend which should call a payment method and then send the response from that service to some other service FTP as a file and it should also transform the response and send it to elastic search rest api and so many other end points. check the camel components https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/index.html

Comment: usually applications use the same protocols to connect to other clients. camel could be the translator of your business logic to different protocols.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How camel knows, for which request i need to send the response. For example, Dispatcher servlet handles the request response behaviour in spring framework, Likewise in camel it passes many components and different endpoints if required. Then how it properly responded to the request that user raised.

Comment: Thanks much Ali momeni, Now it is clear.